# Emdebbed Adobe - how to goto another page in PDF with external buttons?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have pdf embedded in html, pdf embedded object has internal controls & so on. But they are smnall. I need make them bigger. I.e. external.

Now have a problem, - how to make page up/[age down, with external buttons/links?  I try send up/down to holder DIV - but with no effect. Is this ever possible to do ?

I hear that somehow is possible make an images from PDF, but i need this at UNIX hosting, and this will be not an PDF.

Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf). I think you might be able to manipulate embedded PDF with that parameters.

Another approach is to create a set of images from your PDFs using some PDF library.

And another approach is to use Google Docs PDF Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the scroll plugin to make up/down. however you can create the master DIV with static width and height and overflow hidden, and then make the child div inside this. Then with your external buttons, when you click to down, you must be decrease the top of the child DIV. and then you got it.
 have good time.